# How do I change the border color of a Checkbox using JavaScript for Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, checkbox

I am trying to to reproduce this border effect

```js
document.getElementById("e1").style.border='2px solid blue';
```

```html
<input type="text" id="e1">
```

for checkboxes and radio buttons. I have read similar posts to this, but none seem to offer a solution that works. I am using the JavascriptExecutor object in a Java application so keeping the code to JavaScript is the goal. I've read a good approach is to wrap the checkbox with a div, but I am not strong enough with JavaScript to do that.

Ultimately, I'm trying to highlight an element after I change it with Selenium, so even making the Labels bold will suffice. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a span element with the border and replace your checkbox element with it. 
After that, you append the checkbox back to the span element.

```js
const e1 = document.getElementById('e1');
const wrapper = document.createElement('span');
wrapper.style.border = '2px solid blue';

e1.replaceWith(wrapper);
wrapper.append(e1);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="e1">
```

Or a shorter solution is using CSS (outline)

```js
const e1 = document.getElementById('e1');
e1.style.outline = '2px solid blue';
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="e1" >
```

If you can use CSS only

```css
#e1 {
 outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```